# Convert String Date to Date in Apex

Tags: apex, datetime, date

I am using an SOQL in a webservice that is querying the Contact object based on the BirthDate field. The webservice request has the date in the format of 'yyyy-MM-dd',i.e.,1962-01-29 as an example.

I am not able to use this value to query the Contact Object. I tried converting this String Date into Date object. However, it always has 00:00:00 at the end. I tried the below options.

```
String strDate = '1962-01-29';
Date birthDate = Date.valueOf(strDate) ==> This results in 1962-01-29 00:00:00

String strDate = '1962-01-29';
Date dob = Date.valueOf(strDate)
Datetime dt = Datetime.newInstance(dob.Year(),dob.Month(),dob.day());
Date birthDate = dt.date() ==> This also results in 1962-01-29 00:00:00
```

How do I construct a Date object (without time) from the string date '1962-01-29'?

I did search for solutions in various forums and most of them are suggesting the above two solutions only, which does not work. I am not sure whether this behavior was changed in some Salesforce's releases.

Below is the full query that I am using.

```
                String query = 'SELECT id,' +
                                        'LastName,' +
                                        'FirstName,' +
                                        'BirthDate,' +
                                        'MiddleName__c,' +
                                        'MailingAddress,' +
                                        'OtherAddress,' +
                                        'EmploymentStatus__c,' +
                                        'Suffix__c,'+
                                        'Investment_Experience__c ' +
                                'FROM Contact WHERE';
                // Fetching the details of contact based on LastName,FirstName,BirthDate
                if(string.isNotEmpty(lastName)){ //Checking for last name value
                  if(lastName.contains('*') || lastName.contains('%')){
                    lastName = (lastName).replace('*','%');
                    query += ' LastName LIKE \''+lastName+'\' AND';
                  }
                  else{
                    query += ' LastName = \''+lastName+'\' AND'; 
                  }
                }
                if(string.isNotEmpty(firstName)){
                 if(firstName.contains('*') || firstName.contains('%')){
                    firstName = (firstName).replace('*','%');
                    query += ' FirstName LIKE \''+firstName+'\' AND';
                  }
                  else{
                    query += ' FirstName = \''+firstName+'\' AND';   
                    }
                }
                if(string.isNotEmpty(dateOfBirth)){
                    //Datetime dt = Date.valueOf(dateOfBirth);
                    //Datetime dob = Date.newInstance(dt.year(), dt.month(), dt.day());
                    query += ' BirthDate = ' + Date.valueOf(dateOfBirth) + ' AND';
                }
                query += ' Account.OrgNumber__c IN (\''+(string.join(lstOrganizationNumbers,'\',\''))+'\') ';
                query += ' ORDER BY lastName,firstName,BirthDate';
                query += ' LIMIT 50';
                system.debug('Query:: '+query);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance of `Date` has no `Time` attributes, unlike `Datetime`. However, if you *debug* it, the output will show one. This debugging result has ***no impact on how the value will be used in SOQL***.

Your problem is not how you are constructing your date, but likely how you construct your SOQL (which you haven't shown us). If you are building a dynamic query in Apex, you can just bind to a variable in memory (as long as you use no dot reference):

```
Date dateValue = Date.valueOf('1962-01-29');
String soql = 'SELECT Id FROM My_Object__c WHERE Date_Field__c = :dateValue';
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe there's something wrong with your query.
This is your query:

```
SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, BirthDate FROM Contact where BirthDate = 1962-01-29 00:00:00 AND LastName LIKE 'Smith%'
```

You cannot write the date as a literal(with or without single quotes): **1962-01-29 00:00:00**

If you're having trouble with Date Datetime comparissons try to use a dummy range like this one:

```
Date d = Date.parse('2/1/2019');
List<Account> accounts = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE CreatedDate > :d.addDays(-1) AND  CreatedDate < :d.addDays(+1)];
System.debug('Result: ' + accounts);
```

In simple words: Get all the Accounts that were created after yesterday and before tomorrow. Get all accounts from today (or any day between the range).

I highly advise you to go through this Trailhead:
https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_database